# How to GUNZIP and UNTAR a file in one directory and move to another directory in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file named 2014-03-19_cis_digital.tar.gz. in a source directory, i will have to first GUNZIP the file and then UNTAR the file and move the untarred files to another directory.
Can anyone help me in writing the shell script commands??

Answer (score 1):

change your working directory first then untar/ungzip.

```
cd $TARGET_DIR
tar xzf $PATH_TO_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `gunzip` separately. You can do everything in one command:

```
tar -xzf /source/dir/2014-03-19_cis_digital.tar.gz -C /target/dir
```